# Multiple sending parameters using ajax in rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using ajax to send the value of a field and load a selectbox with records this way:

```
  <%= text_field_tag :search, "", id:"RutaId", class:"", style: "display:none;", :'data-remote' => 'true', :'data-url' => url_for(:controller => 'reldaycli', :action => 'busqueda_vendedores_por_ruta', format: 'js')  %>
```

This field is hidden and filled using javascript when clicking on the row of a table, this is the function of javascript:

```
 $("#container_rutas tr").dblclick(function(){
     $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
     var Ruta=$(this).find('.Ruta').html();
     var RutaId=$(this).find('.RutaId').html();
     $("#Ruta").val(Ruta);
     $("#RutaId").val(RutaId);
     $('#vendedor').prop('disabled', true); 
     $('#addruta').modal('hide');

  });
```

The problem is that this way the method I used to send the data to ajax (which is the 'data-remote' that is in the field) does not react unless it is written in the field, but because it is a Hidden field will use the ajax function to fill it

I have been researching and found the solution to add the .change method to the field in the javascript function, like this:

```
$("#RutaId").val(RutaId).change();
```

Making use of the .change sends it, the problem is that it sends multiple times the same data to the controller method, so it does the ajax process and loads the same data several times (2 or 3 times in a row) being that when I type In the field this does not happen and only sends the data only once. What could be?

Answer (score 0):

You could make sure no other events are bound to it.

```
$("RutaId").val(RutaId).unbind().change();
```

Or maybe you have jquery required multiple times and it duplicating the events.
Could also be the change event bubbling up and triggering it multiple times.

Hope it Helps!
Cheers